# Downgrade ipad 9.3.2 to 8.4.1

Tags: ipad, downgrade

My ipad is superrrrrr slow on 9.3.2
Can I downgrade it anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer - No.

---

Long answer:

Any form of a software update (in this case a downgrade) polls Apple's servers to validate the update. This is part of a larger process called signing.

Apple only sign updates for a certain time frame for each iOS revision. Typically, when a new update rolls out, the second most recent firmware is still signed for a couple of weeks before it is no longer signed in place for the new firmware.

iOS 8.4.1 is years out of this window, and iOS 9.3.2 is also no longer being signed also.

This is Apple's way to assure that devices are running the latest version of iOS to promote features to users but more importantly security fixes for vulnerabilities and exploits.